# Can't get angular-material md-sidenav to be 100% height

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm making a new angular2 application using angular2-material with a sidenav.  And I can't for the life of me get that sidenav to have a height of 100%.  I'm trying to get a menu to slide out that takes up the whole height of the screen.  And I want it to open the same way no matter where the user has scrolled.

Here is my template:

```
<md-sidenav-layout class="demo-sidenav-layout">
  <md-sidenav #start mode="over">

    <a [routerLink]="['/login']" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</a>
    <br>
  </md-sidenav>
    <md-toolbar color="primary">

      <button md-button (click)="start.toggle()">Open Side Drawer</button>
      <span>Spellbook</span>

      <span class="demo-fill-remaining">

      </span>

    </md-toolbar>
  <div class="demo-sidenav-content">

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.demo-sidenav-layout {
  //border: 3px solid black;
  min-height:100%;
  md-sidenav {
    padding: 10px;
    background: gainsboro;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
}

.demo-sidenav-content {
  padding: 15px;
  min-height:100%;
}

.demo-toolbar {
  padding: 6px;

  .demo-toolbar-icon {
    padding: 0 14px 0 14px;
  }

  .demo-fill-remaining {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

}
```

I also have `html` set to `height:100%` and `body` set to `min-height:100%`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use **fullscreen**

```
<md-sidenav-layout fullscreen>

  <md-sidenav #start mode="over">
    <a [routerLink]="['/login']" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</a>
    <br>
  </md-sidenav>

  <md-toolbar color="primary">
    <button md-button (click)="start.toggle()">Open Side Drawer</button>
    <span>Spellbook</span>
    <span class="demo-fill-remaining"></span>
  </md-toolbar>

  <div class="demo-sidenav-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>

</md-sidenav-layout>
```

Comment: using fullscreen doesn't let the address bar in mobile browsers collapse while scrolling

Comment: `md-sidenav-layout` is deprectad. This is not valid anymore

Comment: Apparently `md-sidenav-container` is the new name. Source: https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/2183

Comment: md-sidenav-container is the new name for the same and fullscreen is still working with new name.

Comment: If anyone needs a demo of using a fullscreen sidenav I have a plunk [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/AYLl9W/)

Comment: This resolved my Safari height collapse issue using beta.7.

Comment: What is the best way to verify that this attribute (**fullscreen**) is presented in Unit Testing (Jasmine)?

Comment: this answer is outdated. As Kumars answer shows, `fixedInViewport="true"` is the way to go now (checked with Angular Material 6)

Answer (score 62):

Acording to a comment on [Issue : Angular Material 2 - not rendering in full screen](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/759) the fullscreen attribute will be removed...

Try this instead:

```
mat-sidenav-container {
   position: fixed;
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In the latest version this should be .mat-sidenav-container

Comment: As @YesMan85 said, the new version is md-sidenav-container or .mat-sidenav-container. Either way remember to use position: fixed !important; If you don't like using !important in your css you can make use "md-sidenav-container.mat-sidenav-container" to avoid it.

Comment: I've read several statements about `fullscreen` being removed, but it's working for me on beta.7 and seems to be present in beta.12. Does anyone have confirmation of deprecation?

Comment: It's mat-sidenav-container now.  This works good if you have components outside of the container as fullscreen covers the other components.

Comment: This breaks the scroll-to-top functionality when navigating.

Comment: thanks a lot I was stuck with styling .container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
} and header , footer got swallowed

Comment: just add min-height: 100% and no more css

Answer (score 18):

In the latest version of material.angular you can use the property fixedInViewport on mat-sidenav.

See below.

```
<mat-sidenav #start mode="over" fixedInViewport="true"> ... </mat-sidenav>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it moved the left navigations buttons to the top and wide to the 100%

Answer (score 4):

```
  .demo-sidenav-layout {
      position:fixed;
      //border: 3px solid black;
      min-height:100vh;
      md-sidenav {
        padding: 10px;
        background: gainsboro;
        min-height: 100%;
      }
    }
```

make height 100vh instead of 100%....eventhough you can make width = 100% you cannot simply make height 100% at once ,because usually you can scroll down to infinity.
use

```
position:absolute;
```

and then use

```
height : 100%;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set `mad-sidenav-content`'s `min-height` to be `100vh` like so:

`<mat-sidenav-content class="sidenav__content--height"> .... </mat-sidenav-content>`

Where:

```
.sidenav__content--height{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: If you have a `topbar` above your sidebar, change this to `min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);` assuming your topbar is 60px high.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up setting `position:fixed` on the sidenav itself, which gave me exactly what I wanted.

```
.demo-sidenav-layout {
  position:fixed;
  //border: 3px solid black;
  min-height:100%;
  md-sidenav {
    padding: 10px;
    background: gainsboro;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
}

.demo-sidenav-content {
  padding: 15px;
  min-height:100%;
}

.demo-toolbar {
  padding: 6px;

  .demo-toolbar-icon {
    padding: 0 14px 0 14px;
  }

  .demo-fill-remaining {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

}
```