# How to vertically fill the screen with a div while using only material 2 classes and without using css?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am using angular 4 with its respective Material . My app.component.html looks like this :

```
<!--The whole content below can be removed with the new code.-->
<md-toolbar color="primary" >
    <button md-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><md-icon class="md-18|md-
24|md-36|md-48">menu</md-icon></button>
    <span>Material 2</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
</md-toolbar>


<md-sidenav-container layout="column" flex style="background: plum;">

    <md-sidenav #sidenav side="left" class="example-sidenav" flex layout="column" style="background: plum;">
    <md-list>
    <div class="row">
        <md-list-item><md-icon>explore</md-icon> <span>item</span></md-list-item>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <md-list-item><md-icon>map</md-icon> <span>item</span></md-list-item>
    </div>

    <div class="row">    
    <md-list-item><md-icon>home</md-icon> <span>item</span></md-list-item>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <md-list-item><md-icon>android</md-icon> <span>item</span></md-list-item>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <md-list-item><md-icon>done</md-icon> <span>item</span></md-list-item>
    </div>

    </md-list>
    </md-sidenav>


    <md-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px" layout="column" flex>

    </md-grid-list>

</md-sidenav-container>
`
```

[image: The divs expand vertically only till the point they have data defined.]

How to make the `md-sidenav-container` take up all of the space left vertically?

Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/Mvm6zSifW0EpeKtmuSEA?p=preview

Note: I don't want a CSS min-height, height: 100% fix. Only a clean class/directive based solution for Angular Material 2/4.

Comment: To improve your question consider adding a plunker.

Comment: Sure will do that :)

Comment: Plunker has been added

Comment: Why do you not want a css solution? That would be the correct way to do this I believe - what is not "clean" about it?

Comment: @0mpurdy, it isn't. there are classes (notably: layout, flex) for this in the framework already. Adding your own just complicates things.

Comment: Well then I'm learning today as well :)

Comment: @AakashUniyal, the plunker seems to do exactly what you ask for? it fills the entire height of the document?

Comment: @RickvanLieshout It is not filling the screen in the plunker for me [screen shot of behaviour](http://i.imgur.com/vtBtr1R.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `<md-toolbar>` inside the container and add the `fullscreen` attribute to the `<md-sidenav-container>`:

```html
<md-sidenav-container layout="column" flex style="background: plum;" fullscreen>
  <md-toolbar color="primary" >
      <button md-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><md-icon class="md-18|md-24|md-36|md-48">menu</md-icon></button>
      <span>Hems IRCA</span>
      <span class="example-spacer"></span>
  </md-toolbar>

...
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38012519/6894075) for more details

[Updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3EaT5fT6Wdro8MwqWQ4e?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer , fullscreen attribute works well . But i also dont want toolbar to be hidden by the sidenav bar , previously the sidenav bar was below the toolbar . If there is any other way to leverage the fullscreen attribute without hindering the toolbar and sidenav bar structure as mentioned before

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that but you could try the `mode="push"` attribute on the `<side-nav>`